# If I have multiple instances of the same javascript object on a page, how can I select data from a dropdown within a specific one?

Tags: javascript

So I have a widget that needs to be able to run multiple times within the same webpage. I have a dropdown with a list of names, and an Update button. Using:

```
updateBtn.onclick = function() {
        var selected = document.getElementById("list");
        var selectedCompany = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text;
        getData(selectedCompany);
}
```

I'm searching the whole webpage for the first instance of the 'list' drop-down box.

How can I search so I find the value of the drop-down within the same instance of the widget instead?

Comment: They are not the same element, that's the problem: IDs must be **unique**!

Answer (score 0):

If you attach the event listener to all instances of the button, you can use `this` to search up the document tree to get your parent container. Since `this` will reffer to the button you clicked.

Or, attach a unique attribute like `data-button="firstOne"` `data-button="secondOne"` if your system allows for that.

Loose example

```
var selected = this.parentNode.querySelector('#list');
```

Let me know if I misinterpreted your question in any way.